# Best protocol to send huge file over unstable connection

Tags: jms, wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

Use case: Need to send a huge files (multiple of 100 MB) over the queue from one server to another.

At present, am using Activemq Artemis server to send huge file as ByteMessage with help of input stream over tcp protocol with reattempt interval as -1 for unlimited fail over retry. Here the main problem is consumer endpoints connection will be mostly unstable I.e disconnect from network because of mobility nature.

So while send a file in queue, if the connection is dropped and reconnectd broker should resume from where the transaction interrupted (e.g) while tranfer 300 mb of file to consumer queue ,assume that a portion of 100mb is transferred to consumer queue server , then the connection is dropped and reconnected after a while, then process should resume from transferring remaining 200 mb not the whole 300mb again.

My question is which one is the best protocol(tcp, Stomp and openwire) and best practice (blobmessage, bytemessage input stream)to achieve it in ActiveMQ Artemis

Answer (score 1):

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis supports "large" messages which will stream over the network (which uses Netty TCP).  This is covered in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/large-messages.html).  Note: this functionality is only for "core" clients.  It doesn't work with STOMP or OpenWire.  It also doesn't support "resume" functionality where the message transfer will pick-up where it left off in the case of a disconnection.

My recommendation would be to send the message in smaller chunks in individual messages that will be easier to deal with in the case of network slowness or disconnection.  The messages can be grouped together with a correlation ID or something and then the end client can take the pieces of the message and assemble them together once they are all received.